# Strange situation give error: "The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier."

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, bundle

Today I experienced a very strange behavior with my XCode (using Version 4.2, iOS 5.0).

I read some another questions, but my problem is diferent and I never before had this issue.

So, XCode gives me the error "The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier." when I'm trying to run my app on a device (in the simulator just simply does nothing).

I'm sure that the project is correctly set, the bundle ID is correct, my certified is also correct..

I already try a lot of different approaches to solution the problem. Then I realized that it just gives the error when I add a folder to the project with the options "Create folder References for any folder added" selected (like the picture).

[image: adding a folder with folder references option]

I have another apps with folders with folder references, and don't get any error..

Resuming: If I add the folder I get the error, If I don't add a folder, the app runs without any problem..

Could someone help me here trying to figure out whats happens (it's driving me mad).

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I managed to mend the problem. I was adding a folder called "Resources", changing the folder name stops giving me the error.
But I would like to know/understand why was I getting the error..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to mend the problem. I was adding a folder called "Resources", changing the folder name stops giving me the error. But I would like to know/understand why was I getting the error..

Anyway, not a problem anymore..

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing the target name after the icon at the `Add to targets`. Got lost somewhere?

Comment: I clean it..
its the app target

Comment: Have you already done `Validate Settings` in your project info or Build Settings? Another try would be `Product` => `Clean`.

Comment: Yes, of course.. However I managed to mend the problem. I was adding a folder called "Resources", changing the folder name stops giving me the error. Would like to know why..